# Laravel 5 - Update data into 2 related tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 tables relate to each other like that:

```
goals  
| goalId | title   |  

frequencies
| freqId | goalId  |
```

I want to update my tables using Laravel. I did some research on the internet but they just introduce how to update info to only 1 table. I tried to use `Query Builder`, however, it not works. Here is my query:

```
DB::table('goals')
    ->where('goals.goalId', '=', $goaldata['goalid'])
    ->where('goals.goalId', '=', 'frequencies.goalId')
    ->update([  
    // my query
]);
```

This is my fully statement if you want to look inside my query for more detail: http://pastebin.com/CmbReqGq
How can I update data into 2 tables ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using migrations you could use the `onUpdate('cascade')` which will update a single field when the parent table is updated.

Alternatively, if you are wanting to update a large amount of fields you could use a mysql trigger which would fire when an event is hit. like so:

```
DB::unprepared("
            CREATE TRIGGER new_your_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON goals FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN

             UPDATE frequencies SET id = NEW.id ;

            END
        ");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, a SQL Trigger seem to be hard for me to understand and using. And I also solve my problem above by using `DB::raw` to write raw SQL query in Laravel

Answer (score 0):

this is a lot simpler

```
$data = ['id' => 1,'name' =>'John'];
$query = Model::update($data);
// to get the update row id
return $query -> id;
```

use the return id to insert or update data in related tables